# Auto indent in JetBrains IntelliJ/PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using the PhpStorm.

CODE SAMPLE

```
.head { ~~ }
.body { ~~ }
#body div { ~~ }
```

If I use the auto indent (`Ctrl+ alt + L`) then I got this:

```
.head { ~~ }


.body { ~~ }


#body div { ~~ }
```

I hate that blank line.

How to remove the blank line?

Comment: *"If I use the auto indent (ctrl+ alt + L)"* It's not "auto indent". It's Code Reformat. You can configure your rules in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style`

Comment: I Know, BUT HOW TO CHANGE THE CODE REFORMAT. THAT CASE NOT FOUND.

Answer (score 1):

In **File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | CSS | Other**, set **Blank lines between blocks:** to `0` - does it help?

Note that upcoming PhpStorm 2018.3 will include more code style options for CSS - see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/10/webstorm-2018-3-eap-6/